# Conditional formatting of an entire row based on multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make a conditional formatting rule in Google Spreadsheet that would highlight a row green based on text in multiple cells.

If cells L2, M2, and N2 = APPROVED; and cell O2 = X; then row 2 = highlighted green.

Answer (score 2):

Apply to a range such as A2:Z the conditional formatting with the custom formula

```
=and($L2="APPROVED", $M2="APPROVED", $N2="APPROVED", $O2 = "X")
```

#### Explanation

- The formula is written as it should be applied to the upper left corner of the range, that is A2 here.
- Dollar signs are used to make column references absolute, so that, for example, formatting of cell B2 would still refer to O2 and not to P2.
- The row references are relative, so that, for example, third row cells refer to L3, M3, N3, and O3.